# Search using a Predicate on a Domain Class

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

In LINQ to Objects, one can easily filter for a subset of a collection using a predicate, e.g. if my domain class is `Person` the collection is `persons`, and the predicate `Func<Person, bool> filter`, it would be something like `persons.Where(filter).ToArray()`.

The same functions with a collection of persons serialized as an `XElement`:

```
XElement[] xFiltered = xPersons.Elements("Person")
                               .Where(xFilter)
                               .ToArray();
```

where `xPersons` is the root element containing the persons' elements (each named "Person"), `Func<XElement, bool> xFilter` a predicate defined over `XElement`as an argument type.

I wonder if there exists a straightaway possibility to create a `Where` statement in LINQ for XML that would take a predicate of type `Func<Person, bool>` as an argument, instead of `Func<XElement, bool>`? To do so, one would need to implement a converter to transform `Func<Person, bool>` into `Func<XElement, bool>`, but this seems to be a counter-intuitive, error-prone exercise. Can a genuine converter of such kind be envisaged (e.g. based on inspection)? Or does it simply exist?

Comment: We don't know how you'd construct a `Person` from an `XElement` at the moment... once you've got that, the rest is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a predicate on underlying XElement(s) and XAttribute(s), e.g.

```
xPersons.Elements("Person")
        .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("Name") == "Alex")
```

To use class `Person` you need to deserialize it first:

```
xPersons.Elements("Person")
        .Select(e => CreatePerson(e))
        .Where(p => p.Name == "Alex")

private static Person CreatePerson(XElement element)
{
    // your (de)serialization logic goes here
}
```

or you can write an explicit cast operator in your class:

```
xPersons.Elements("Person")
        .Where(e => ((Person)e).Name) == "Alex")

public static explicit operator Person(XElement element)
{
    // your (de)serialization logic goes into your Person class
}
```

Comment: Yes, the class Person has a FromXElement(XElement x) function which is equivalent to your solution. But this would (imho) be the same if I deserialize the whole collection and then filter it with a Func<Person, bool>.

Comment: @AlexKonnen: Yes, you can serialize each element or the whole collection. This is the only way I see to used class Person rather than XML content.